# Failed to speedup calculation with multi core calculations

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

I tried to speed up my computation time using multicore computation. Below is my code

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import pandas as pd
import time

data = pd.DataFrame({'val' : range(100000)})

def process(i):
    return data.copy().loc[i, 'val'] * data.loc[i, 'val']


start1 = time.time()    
results1 = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(process)(i) for i in range(data.shape[0]))
end1 = time.time()

start2 = time.time()    
results2 = Parallel(n_jobs=1)(delayed(process)(i) for i in range(data.shape[0]))
end2 = time.time()

print(end1 - start1)
print(end2 - start2)
```

However as you see despite using only one core, the second approach is only slower than the first one by a small amount of time. I expected that runtime in second approach should be 4 times higher than the first one

Could you please help me to understand if there is anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected : **`data` is fully copied for each `process` call** done 100_000 times here, so the execution time is **quadratic**. This is a very *expensive* operation on large datadrames. Multiplying integers or FP numbers is pretty cheap. **Memory is often a bottleneck**. **Copies should be avoided** for sake of performance. Copies do not scale well because using many cores does not make DRAM accesses much faster on most platforms (e.g. 2 cores are often enough to saturate the DRAM on most PC).

Here, this is even worse since each item is extracted separately and 100_000 `delayed` calls are done with 100_000 Python function calls. There is a good chance for the main loop iterating on all items to be much slower than the actual computation so **workers are starving** during this iteration. I think this is the main issue. You should **operate on chunks** to avoid such a very expensive iteration. By the way `loc[i, 'val']` is known to be very slow though it should not impact scalability.

For sake of performance, you should perform the operation **in-place** on the dataframe and in a **vectorized** way, that is, mutate it. For (CPython) parallelism to be useful here, the operation needs to be much more expensive than that (and less memory-bound). Actually, `data['val'].to_numpy() ** 2` is certainly memory-bound because the result is a temporary Numpy array (Pandas series are slower here and AFAIK Pandas uses Numpy internally).